# Is there a way to see how many votes I have left for the day?

Tags: support, voting, user-interface

Is there a way to see how many votes I have left for the day (prior to the 5 votes left warning)?

Comment: [Related.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/) (Search down to the text `basic voting statistics` to see how to get this information, as well as an explanation for why it was added.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no easy way to view your remaining votes for the day. Details on this can be found in answers provided by [Rebecca Chernoff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67984/any-easy-way-to-see-how-many-of-my-30-votes-i-have-remaining-for-today/67985#67985) and [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1967/display-the-number-of-votes-a-user-has-left-for-the-day/2056#2056).

Answer (score 2):

Your profile shows the number of votes you've cast today. This and other voting totals are tallied at the lower-right corner of the `summary` tab, even though they're not shown in the `votes` tab itself.

For example, this is what that looks like right now, for my meta user:

---

[image]

---

Subtract that number from 40, and that's how many votes you have left today.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see the votes remaining is hover the cursor over the down tick button on the name of a user.

[image]

It will show, how many votes the user has already given. Subtract this number from 40 if the votes on questions are 1:3 in ratio with answer. Subtract this from 30 otherwise. As [this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3399/61218) suggests.

Comment: Nice badge icons!