# How to get Vox Populi badge

Tags: discussion, voting, badges

If I know right i can use maximum 30 votes in day. How can i get  `Vox Populi`  badge when it needs 40 votes:

> **Vox Populi** Used the maximum 40 votes in a day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is covered by this [MetaStackoverflow Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached)

... plagarising unashamedly....

> This is totally by design...
>
> If 1 in 3 of your votes are on questions, you will get 40 votes.
>
> If you vote on less questions than that you will get less (lowest is
>   30)

... and Jeff Atwood has a [great blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/) - its well worth a read.

> So how do we encourage people to remember the questions when voting?
>   Perhaps we should institute a new policy: every time you forget to
>   vote a great question up, or a bad question down — a kitten gets it!

[image]

... but he is only kidding... honest!

Comment: Voting on questions rocks! My advice to anyone who so far votes just on answers: Try voting on questions, and you won't be disappointed. And remember that, much of the time (though there are exceptions), a good answer happened because there was a good question *to answer*. By voting up the good question, you ensure that the good answer will be seen (and voted on) by even more people.

Comment: My loose "policy" when upvoting an answer is to also seriously consider upvoting the question *unless* it's somewhat localized (e.g. *why does make fail when I try to compile blah package from source?*). A lot of flaggable questions should also, in @jokerdino's words, be "downvoted ruthlessly."

Comment: I have only known this after reading the question. I think I have good voting pattern. (144/295) are on questions. (*shameless self-promotion*)

Comment: @izx FYI, [I didn't get pinged for that comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). And, I requested that those questions be downvoted "mercilessly" :P. I received quite a bit of flak during that time. I generally try to upvote as many questions and answers as possible. These days, I only downvote if it is blatant spam or crap post.